# Background Image in Linearlayout

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout

I am setting an image for the background of a linearlayout that I am using. The problem I am getting is the white border just below the title bar. If I set the background to a color the white border does not appear. Does anybody know what might be causing this.

[image: background image problem]

I am loading some content in dynamically but here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gestures"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gestureStrokeType="single"
    android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:uncertainGestureColor="#00000000"
    android:gestureColor="#00000000">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dip"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
<!--     android:background="@drawable/background"> -->


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/item_text"
        android:textColor="#fffafa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/photoLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"/>     

     <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutDynamic"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/my_border">

     </LinearLayout>

     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/item_text1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="20dip"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Besonderheiten"
        android:textColor="#fffafa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/my_border">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">   


            <TextView 
                style="@style/CodeFont"
               android:id="@+id/item_wasteDisposal"
               android:text="@string/item_wasteDisposal"
               android:textSize="14sp"
               android:singleLine="true"/>  

            <ImageView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/wasteDisposalImage"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_wasteDisposal"
                android:padding="5dp"/>

            <View
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:background="#FF909090"
                android:layout_below="@id/wasteDisposalImage"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>


            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/internetImage"
                android:layout_below="@id/wasteDisposalImage"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/wasteDisposalImage"
                android:padding="5dp"/>

            <TextView 
                style="@style/CodeFont"
                android:id="@+id/item_internet"
                android:text="@string/item_internet"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/internetImage"
                android:layout_below="@id/wasteDisposalImage"/>

            <View
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:background="#FF909090"
                android:layout_below="@id/internetImage"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>


            <ImageView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/overnightStayImage"
                android:layout_below="@id/internetImage"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/internetImage"
                android:padding="5dp"/>

            <TextView 
                style="@style/CodeFont"
                android:id="@+id/item_overnightStay"
                android:text="@string/item_overnightStay"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/overnightStayImage"
                android:layout_below="@id/internetImage"/>  

                            <View
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:background="#FF909090"
                android:layout_below="@id/overnightStayImage"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

            <ImageView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/toiletImage"
                android:layout_below="@id/overnightStayImage"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/overnightStayImage"
                android:padding="5dp"/>

            <TextView 
                style="@style/CodeFont"
                android:id="@+id/item_toilet"
                android:text="@string/item_toilet"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/toiletImage"
                android:layout_below="@id/overnightStayImage"/>

                            <View
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:background="#FF909090"
                android:layout_below="@id/toiletImage"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

            <ImageView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/electricityImage"
                android:layout_below="@id/toiletImage"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/toiletImage"
                android:padding="5dp"/>

            <TextView 
                style="@style/CodeFont"
                android:id="@+id/item_electricity"
                android:text="@string/item_electricity"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/electricityImage"
                android:layout_below="@id/toiletImage"/>                

                        <View
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:background="#FF909090"
                android:layout_below="@id/electricityImage"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

            <ImageView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/cranImage"
                android:layout_below="@id/electricityImage"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/electricityImage"
                android:padding="5dp"/>

            <TextView 
                style="@style/CodeFont"
                android:id="@+id/item_cran"
                android:text="@string/item_cran"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/cranImage"
                android:layout_below="@id/electricityImage"/>        

                            <View
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:background="#FF909090"
                android:layout_below="@id/cranImage"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>                   

            <ImageView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/slipwayImage"
                android:layout_below="@id/cranImage"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/cranImage"
                android:padding="5dp"/> 

            <TextView 
                style="@style/CodeFont"
                android:id="@+id/item_slipway"
                android:text="@string/item_slipway"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/slipwayImage"
                android:layout_below="@id/cranImage"/>  

                        <View
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:background="#FF909090"
                android:layout_below="@id/slipwayImage"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

            <ImageView 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/campingImage"
                android:layout_below="@id/slipwayImage"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/slipwayImage"
                android:padding="5dp"/> 

            <TextView 
                style="@style/CodeFont"
                android:id="@+id/item_camping"
                android:text="@string/item_camping"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/campingImage"
                android:layout_below="@id/slipwayImage"/>       

                            <View
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:background="#FF909090"
                android:layout_below="@id/campingImage"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/freshWaterImage"
                android:layout_below="@id/campingImage"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/campingImage"
                android:padding="5dp"/> 

            <TextView 
                style="@style/CodeFont"
                android:id="@+id/item_freshWater" 
                android:text="@string/item_freshWater"
               android:textSize="14sp"
               android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/freshWaterImage"
                android:layout_below="@id/campingImage"/>  

        </RelativeLayout>   

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: it can be the scrollview borders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Post your image file. And is it a 9-patch png or just a standard image file? Without more info my guess that your image is too big for your space, and for some reason when it shrinks it down it has to shrink in both directions and it creates blank space at the top. I have noticed this effect before. If that is what is happening then solutions would be either resize the image file to smaller so that it won't have to shrink, or (and this is probably the prefered way) create a a very small 9-patch that will expand into the image you want. It is hard for me to tell but it looks like from the picture your image is just a solid color anyway, so if you went the 9-patch route you could make it a very small canvas size 10 x 10 pixels or something. and it would know how to expand it to fill any space required.

Another way to tell if this is what is going on is run your app on something with a bigger screen. Then it won't have to shrink the image file and thus should not show the blank space at the top

Comment: it's a png image that is rather big. I will test some of your suggestions now

Comment: Ok I think that is your problem then, either chop it down to screen size and leave it a png or make it tiny and make it into a 9-patch and you should be good to go.

Comment: You was correct with the image being big and then getting resized. It would have took me a long time to figure that out

Comment: Yeah that one took me a while, I am not sure why it does that when it scrunches.