# Android, background drawable appear black in genymotion but looks fine in intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea, genymotion

I'm trying to set background image for my activity like this:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/login_background"
            android:orientation="vertical">
```

which looks great in the preview in intellij

[image]

but in genymotion it looks black:

[image]

after trying to change the name of the file, the size of the file and trying various export methods from photoshop, I'm clueless.

Any ideas?

Comment: This image is most probably very large and you might be getting an exception somewhere in your console.Please check for that .

Comment: I don't see any error regarding the size. Besides, it's 1080X1920 .. is that something that can be a problem?

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993518/background-image-in-linearlayout

Comment: It can't be too big. I just resized it to be 300X533 and it still act like that. I can see this error in the console, maybe it related. `08-04 05:33:39.171    3579-3579/com.yesno.yesno E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
08-04 05:33:39.171    3579-3579/com.yesno.yesno E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
08-04 05:33:39.179    3579-3579/com.yesno.yesno E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
08-04 05:33:39.183    3579-3579/com.yesno.yesno E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384`

Comment: I have only xhdpi and xxhdpi. I'm testing it in a nexus 5 virtual device ...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried another genymotion config yet?
Or have you tried it on a real Device?

I would suggest to use some other Configuration first, according to this post it could help.

https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/298

PS: I know not a real answer, got not enough reputation yet, thought i could help anyway.

Comment: I just figured out that it indeed only genymotion memory problem. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

After playing with the issue more I truly don't know what was the problem. After trying the same image in different activity it started to show even without modified the genymotion settings.